# karma trouble with angular constant

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I had working tests before a merge of 2 branches.  The new branch brought along an angular constant which I believe broke all the tests.
I have an angular constant like so

```
...
return $http.get(ENV+'/api/url').then(function (response) {
                appName.constant("userinfo", response.data);
                userID = response.data.user.id;
            }, function(errorResponse) {...
```

and my test controller set up like this

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('appName');
    return inject(function($injector) {
      //nothing here yet
    });
  });
```

I was able to shorten the amount of errors by creating this stub for the constant that my tests would use

```
angular.module('appName').constant('userinfo', {
  user: {
    id: 0
  }
});

window.ENVApp = '/ng-app'
```

And I am running into this error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.10/$injector/unpr?p0=httpInterceptorProvider%20%3C-%20httpInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20ModalService%20%3C-%20taOptions

The files are loaded into karma.conf.  Any ideas how to get around this error? My tests wont run because of this issue.

Comment: The whole point of a constant is it's constant (i.e., you can't fetch it from an api call)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you returning from `beforeEach`?

`beforeEach` shouldn't return anything. It should just do some setup, set some variables, etc.

Also, I think there is a problem with passing `$injector` to the `inject` callback. I think you need to wrap it with `_`'s as in `_$injector_`. However it's unclear why you want to use the `$injector` service in your test.